# Password hashing and special characters?

Tags: hash, passwords

Does any hashing algorithm exclude special characters?

Just tried to register at HP and here is what i got, do they store passwords as plaintext?

[image]

Comment: It appears that whoever wrote their login stuff is an idiot.

Comment: You can't know for certain whether they're storing it in plaintext just because they don't allow these characters; my guess would be that at some point it was and their password policy has simply persisted even if the passwords now in the DB are hashed. They can't spell, either.

Comment: 1. If they remind you a forgotten password (instead of resetting), they surely keep plaintext passwords.

2. This Could be crappy techniques to avoid script injection (XSS, SQL injection, php injection etc.)

Comment: @TCS password must be destroyed just after your account creation! so even the user forgets it, you make a function to RESET a new password, and about the characters, it seems that now all language offers character escaping? a big boss like HP cant get it?

Comment: @AbdelouahabPp Password must be destroyed, but I see here-and-there websites that still resend you the real password. Also, character escaping does not protect you completely from script injection, but its a good hardening.

I hope HP gets all that, but I can't explain that weird restriction.

Comment: Just another idea from the top of my head. Maybe they use these characters as delimiters later on the server side?!

Comment: @TCS so if you hack their database, you just try to put them on emails since lot of people use the same password for all their accounts :(
and what do you mean by delimiters? for what?

Comment: @AbdelouahabPp By writing "delimieters", I mean that *maybe* they concatenate strings on the server side, for instance "firstname|lastname|password&confirmemail=true". So on the server side they could use these strings as delimiters to split the string. You can't really tell, these are all guesses to try and figure out this weird constraint.

Comment: so this is about the form so the | will be used to extract data (something like `split("|")`) in python.
but yes, this is really bizarre! hope we will know the idea behind

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course no, as hashing algorithms work with streams of bytes, not with characters. So making some of those bytes special is a nonsense.

It's hard to tell why do they have such a weird restriction but it definitely has nothing to do with hashing.

Comment: i said that maybe they was using Peppers, this but even this will use any kind of UTF characters ?

Comment: @AbdelouahabPp I'm sorry, what is “Peppers”?

Comment: this is like Salt, but instead of storing it in the database with the password, it is stored in your application code, so it will be use with your password and be hashed, this will not let the hacker to guess the salt since it is not stored in database

Comment: @AbdelouahabPp: Ah, so like salting, but worse!

Comment: @OliCharlesworth yes, in the case where the source code of your login function will get seen :p

Comment: They can use salt, pepper, whatever. Hashing algorithms just don't care, they are working with _bytes_.

Comment: so it must be some primate algorithm to avoid sql injection :(
thank you :)

Comment: @AbdelouahabPp Those characters have absolutely nothing to do with SQL. SQL has `AND` and `OR` operators.

Comment: sql injection can use the quotes?

Comment: @AbdelouahabPp well, you can use almost anything for SQL injections, so, if your question is “Do you need any of those symbols to perform an SQL injection?” the answer is “Not at all.”

Comment: so then HP is making something really bizarre by excluding those characters ;)